# ManualResetEvent on Async TCP

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I'm trying to create a simple TCP Async client using Windows Forms, but seems that my connection callbacks and methods don't have access to my ManualResetEvents, because the main thread get stuck waiting for the reset. What am I doing wrong?

I'm following the this MS example code: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-client-socket-example

Those ManualResetEvents are a cool way to synchronize threads and I want to use it in this project.

Thanks for the help!

```
namespace Simple_TCP_Client
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        {
            public Socket workSocket = null;
            public const int BufferSize = 256;
            public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
            public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        }
        public static ManualResetEvent connectDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        public static ManualResetEvent sendDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        public static ManualResetEvent receiveDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        public static String response = String.Empty;

        private void StartClient(IPAddress ipAddress, int portnum)
        {
            try
            {
                IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, portnum);
                Socket client = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily,
                    SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                client.BeginConnect(remoteEP,
                    new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
                connectDone.WaitOne();
                Send(client, "Hello Server!");
                sendDone.WaitOne();
                Receive(client);
                receiveDone.WaitOne();
                WriteOnLog("Response received : " + response.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                WriteOnLog(e.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
                client.EndConnect(ar);

                WriteOnLog("Socket connected to " +
                    client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
                connectDone.Set();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                WriteOnLog(e.ToString());
            }
        }
        private void Receive(Socket client)
        {
            try
            {
                StateObject state = new StateObject();
                state.workSocket = client;
                client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                    new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                WriteOnLog(e.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
                Socket client = state.workSocket;
                int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);
                if (bytesRead > 0)
                {
                 state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));
                    client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                        new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (state.sb.Length > 1)
                    {
                        response = state.sb.ToString();
                    }
                    receiveDone.Set();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                WriteOnLog(e.ToString());
            }
        }
        private void Send(Socket client, String data)
        {
            byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
            client.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), client);
        }

        private void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
                int bytesSent = client.EndSend(ar);
                WriteOnLog("Sent " + bytesSent + " bytes to server.");
                sendDone.Set();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                WriteOnLog(e.ToString());
            }
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        delegate void WriteOnLogCallback(string text);

        private void WriteOnLog(string text)
        {
            if (this.listBox1.InvokeRequired)
            {
                WriteOnLogCallback d = new WriteOnLogCallback(WriteOnLog);
                this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
            }
            else
            {
                this.listBox1.Items.Add(text);
            }
        }
        private void btn_connect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IPAddress ipAddress;
            int portNum;
            if (IPAddress.TryParse(txt_ip.Text, out ipAddress) && int.TryParse(txt_port.Text, out portNum))
            {
                StartClient(ipAddress, portNum);
                btn_connect.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Enter a Valid Server's IP Address and Port",
             "Invalid Address or Port", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "don't have access"? Do you get an error message? Which?

Comment: My main thread get stuck, waiting for the callbacks set the ManualResetEvent. If I comment the .WaitOne() lines, my code runs smoothly. So I think maybe my callbacks can't set the ManualResetEvent or even my main thread can't read them, that's why it get stuck.

Comment: Hey, please post full code here. You have `ConnectCallback` method and others.

Comment: If you want to wait for the connect to complete anyhow, why not just use the synchronous form [Socket.Connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.connect)

Comment: Do you need to synchronize threads or to have async tcp client? These are not the same. For async microsoft provides a way to convert old async patterns(BeginSomething or events). I cannot find the article on msdn, but here is an example https://blog.rsuter.com/create-task-based-method-from-legacy-callback-method/

Comment: And so having it async with TaskCompletionSource shoukd make it more readable

Comment: DmitriyPolyanskiy, I've just posted the full code. Sorry taking so long to answer.
KlausGütter, I rather use async sockets because I don't want to lock my main thread while the client is waiting for the connection.
Viktor Arsanov, TaskCompletionSource seems a cool way to do it! I'll try that!

Comment: You cannot easily copy and paste code from a console application to a WinForms project, as the threading model differs enough (common practice to block main thread in console apps, but never do that in WinForms apps). You should search if there are samples on sites like GitHub about how to use TCP properly in WinForms.

Comment: @LexLi, yeah I noticed that it's very common to see this kind of strategy being used on console apps, but I couldn't find any WinForms application like this... I'll just remove those lines and move on! Thanks anyhow!